# Why doesn't my server attempt to use more resources for a heavy mysql search?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I have a mysql table with about 90k rows. I have a routine I've written which loops through each one of these rows, and then crosschecks the results within another table with about 90k rows. If there is a match, I delete one of the rows. All the columns I'm cross checking I've made indexes in mysql.

When I run this script on a dedicated local server with 2 x quad 2.4ghz intel xeon, 24gb of ram (with php memory_limit set to 12288m), and with an SSD, the whole script takes about a minute to complete. I would imagine then that the servers resources are maxing out, but actually CPU is about 93% idle, ram is utilising about 6% and I'm looking at Read/Writes on the SSD and it's like not much is happening at all.

I mentioned the problem to somebody else who said that the problem is I'm executing a single-threaded process and wondering why it's not using all 8 processors, but even so, is checking through a mysql table 90k times really a big deal? Wouldn't at least one CPU be running at max?

Why doesn't my server attempt to throw more resources at the script when I run it? Or, how can I unleash more resources so that my local web app runs not like a low spec'd VPS?

Comment: Have you considered writing a query that exploits the fact you have a _relational database_ to solve your problem in better than quadratic time?

That's what relational databases are _for_.

Comment: I have not ventured into those daunting relational db waters yet, I'm afraid. I tend to do simple queries and do most of the legwork with php, which it appears really sucks doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of the rows, 90K rows isn't a whole lot. Odds are they're all cached in RAM.

As for the CPUs, your process is not quite single threaded, but it's pretty close. Both your process and the DB server are separate processes, the problem is of course that your process stops while the DB server processes the request, so whatever core has your process scheduled shuts down just as the one with DB spools up.

As the commenter mentioned, it's likely you can do this more efficiently by offloading most of the processing to the DB server. Most of your time is just in statement overhead sending 90K SQL statements to the server.

Comment: I just worked out how to do the same loop within mysql and saw for the first time mysql using up 100% of a cpu.  Very Cool. Cheers